# Python selenium gives error while fetch nth element

Tags: python, css, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors

```
<div class="booking-classes">
   <h3 style="text-align: center;">
      <p><a href="https://foreupsoftware.com/index.php/booking/20290#/teetimes" style="background-position:0px 0px;"><b><i><span style="font-size:16pt;line-height:115%;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;color:rgb(42,100,150);">Click
         here to return to the main book a tee time page</span></i></b></a>
      </p>
      <p><br></p>
      <p><span style="font-weight:700;color:rgb(51,51,51);font-family:'Arial Rounded MT Bold', sans-serif;font-size:16px;text-align:center;"><span style="font-size:14pt;">Restrooms are currently closed and only port-a-john facilities are available.</span></span><br></p>
   </h3>
   <div>
      <div class="row" style="margin-top: 1em;">
         <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4">
            <label for="schedule_select" class="hidden-xs">Facility</label>
            <select id="schedule_select" name="schedules" class="form-control schedules">
               <option value="3782" selected="">
                  Hominy Hill
               </option>
               <option value="3778">
                  Bel-Aire 18 Holes
               </option>
               <option value="3779">
                  Bel-Aire 9 Holes
               </option>
               <option value="3780">
                  Charleston Springs North Course
               </option>
               <option value="3781">
                  Charleston Springs South Course
               </option>
               <option value="3783">
                  Howell Park
               </option>
               <option value="4234">
                  Howell Park Back 9
               </option>
               <option value="3784">
                  Pine Brook
               </option>
               <option value="3785">
                  Shark River
               </option>
               <option value="3969">
                  Shark River Back 9
               </option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-primary col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4">Passing</button>
   <button class="btn btn-primary col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4">The</button>
   <button class="btn btn-primary col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4">Parcel</button>
</div>
```

In the above element if you see the div class `booking-classes` has 5 children `h3, div, button, button, button` I need to get the 5th element button inside it.

This is what I tried :

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.booking-classes:nth-child(4)'
```

But this gives me error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.booking-classes:nth-child(5)"}
```

I tried to get 3rd 4th etc as well but none of them are workingm but when I do 0th element, entire `booking-class` element is returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div.booking-classes:nth-child(4)
```

This piece of code means: Find div of class booking-classes which is 4th element of it's parent.
What are you looking for is

```
div.booking-classes > button.nth-child(x)
```

Edit:
To get nth child of any type use

```
div.booking-classes > *:nth-child(x)
```

Where x is index of the child

Comment: what would be x?  also Its not guranteed that would be a button it could be a div as well, so can't use button while fetching nth element

Comment: x would be index of the element, if you want to iterate over every child of element consider using for loop instead of search for every element by locator

Comment: so its not possible to get nth child inside an elemnt?

Comment: does the element you are looking for has specific class?

Comment: nope it does not

Comment: well, you could try something like this div.booking-classes > *:nth_child(4)